# How do I crack into this encrypted XML?

Tags: xml, security, encryption, aes

I'm doing a project for a company that's had software built by another firm some years ago. Trouble is they have built the app with VB6 and conveniently stored the data in encrypted XML files. "Encrypted XML?!", you may ask? Yes, its apparently block encrypted complete with embedded key. I'm no expert in crypto, so I'm calling for help. Any idea which cipher I should use to decrypt this?

**Format:** (notice that the file is split into 2 parts ... key & data)

```
   <CryptoXML>

     <EncryptedKey>
        <CipherData>
            <CipherValue><![CDATA[.........]]></CipherValue>
        </CipherData>
     </EncryptedKey>

     <EncryptedData Type="LanguageDefs">
        <CipherData>
             <CipherValue><![CDATA[..........]]></CipherValue>
        </CipherData>
     </EncryptedData>

   </CryptoXML>
```

And here's the full [XML file](http://www.mediafire.com/?5wcb9k7h42ue7a9) if you want to try.

Comment: Can I have some help about the cipher used? All people keep saying is that the key I have here is useless. Can someone recommend some approach so I can at least try?

Comment: I think you have trouble listening to people in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want us to guess the key or you have the key? I am 99,9% sure that the key is encoded in the application and with enough patience you can get it from there. The XML block itself looks like the one following XMLEnc standard, so you can use the library of your choice to handle the data (if you have a key).

Comment: Hey, the key seems to be within the "EncryptedKey" section above.... the XML file is split into 2 parts .... one for the key and one for the data. I think it is fully self contained. Can you tell me how to decrypt the data? which cipher? AES?

Comment: @Jenko no, EncryptedKey is a different story. EncryptedKey is a key, used to encrypt the data, right. But this EncryptedKey itself is in encrypted form and you need to have the key (different one) to decrypt EncryptedKey.

Comment: I think EncryptedKey is not encrypted, but it is simply binary data stored in a text format. Its what I would do if I wanted some quick-n-dirty encryption. Place the key AND the data nearby, use the key to decrypt the data. So I'm planning on reading the data as binary, but then I still need the cipher. What makes you think the key is encrypted?

Comment: @Jenko: The name is *EncryptedKey* (not *EncryptionKey* or similar), which sounds like it is encrypted.

Comment: @Jenko based on tag names this looks like XMLEnc and if it is XMLEnc, then Encrypted key is the encrypted session key. And recipient must have a key to decrypt the session key. Anyway if you think you know better, then why asking on SO - try decrypting it yourself.